# Jni build with Android studio error: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found

Tags: android, c, android-studio, java-native-interface

Because some reason, I have to generate some text from C. So, I wrote some C method for that purpose. I build the Jni with Android studio, and it seem work fine with my 5.1.0 Genymotion emulator. 
But when I run the build on 4.1.1 emulator, I got this issue :

```html
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
```

After researching. Maybe the problem is from building jni issue, that I haven't build the *.so file for x86. But when I decompile the apk, it seem that the *.so file already in "x86" folder.

[image]

Here is the android.mk file that I get from app's build folder :

```html
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ofx
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--build-id
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    xxx.../app/src/main/jni/key/Base64Util.c \
    xxx.../app/src/main/jni/key/hidingutil.c \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += xxx.../app/src/main/jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += xxx.../app/src/Beneficiary/jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += xxx.../app/src/debug/jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += xxx.../app/src/BeneficiaryDebug/jni

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please help me make sure that the build will be fine to all devices, It will be very appreciated. I don't have many devices to take test on.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android.mk file I don't see that you any prebuilt libs set as resources. This could help in the inclusion.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := module_name 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/prebuilt_lib_name.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is a Bash Script to help, add your ABI platforms in the APP_ABI area and change filepaths as necessary. No need to keep recompiling the whole thing altogether, but this will automate your native *.so  builds and you can use gradle to do the rest:

```
ndk-build APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_LOG=true

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    rm -rf build/native-libs/

    cd libs
    for i in *

    #rm -v */libofx.so

    for arch in *
    do
        builddir=../build/native-libs/$arch
        mkdir -p $builddir
        cp -v $arch/*.so  $builddir
    done
fi
```

Comment: thank for your comment. But could you tell me exactly where should I put the script to ?

Comment: Added new bits to above, the bash script you would put in the top folder of your project like your main linker files.

Comment: thank a lot for your help. But I found out it's not because of the *.SO file problem. You can see from my answer.

Comment: Cool, glad it came through. Hopefully this information will still be useful to you, especially in the long term and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution from this [post](http://www.rajatswarup.com/blog/2015/02/24/genymotion-and-libhoudini-so-error/). 
It's because genymotion emulator need ARM translation library. You can download it from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2680937&d=1397258016). Hope it would help someone.